# How to combine list of records with tree of parent record pointers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree-traversal

I have data like this:

```js
const listOfRecords = Array.from({ length: 10000 }, (x, i) => ({ id: i + 1 }))

const treeOfParents = {
  id: 1,
  children: [
    {
      id: 1,
      children: [
        {
          id: 3,
          children: [
            {
              id: 3,
              children: [
                {
                  id: 5,
                },
                {
                  id: 10,
                },
                {
                  id: 17,
                },
                {
                  id: 321,
                },
              ]
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 401,
          children: [
            {
              id: 401,
              children: [
                {
                  id: 405,
                },
                {
                  id: 410,
                },
                {
                  id: 417,
                },
                {
                  id: 499,
                },
              ]
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 1010,
          children: [
            {
              id: 1021,
              children: [
                {
                  id: 1023,
                },
                {
                  id: 1026,
                },
                {
                  id: 1051,
                },
                {
                  id: 1065,
                },
              ]
            },
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 1099,
      children: [
        {
          id: 1099,
          children: [
            {
              id: 1103,
              children: [
                {
                  id: 1104,
                },
                {
                  id: 1111,
                },
                {
                  id: 1200,
                },
                {
                  id: 1400,
                },
              ]
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 1591,
          children: [
            {
              id: 1591,
              children: [
                {
                  id: 1591,
                },
                {
                  id: 1701,
                },
                {
                  id: 1821,
                },
                {
                  id: 1900,
                },
              ]
            },
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}


traverse(treeOfParents)

console.log(JSON.stringify(treeOfParents, null, 2))

function traverse(tree) {
  const traversed = iterativeDFS(tree)
  let i = 0
  while (i < traversed.length) {
    let current = traversed[i++]
    let next = traversed[i]

    // mutable hack
    current.records = []

    if (!next) return

    // get diff to know how many records to add.
    let diff = next.id - current.id
    let records = listOfRecords.splice(0, diff)
    current.records.push(...records)
  }
}

function iterativeDFS(start) {
  const stack = [start]
  const result = []
  while (stack.length) {
    const node = stack.pop()
    result.push(node)
    node.children?.forEach(child => {
      stack.push(child)
    })
  }
  return result
}
```

I just generated a list of 10,000 records by incrementing an ID, and made up a tree which is a partial tree based on my data. The nodes in the tree connect to IDs in the list **in order**, *but* it gathers chunks at certain points. By that I mean, for example, at depth 3 (position 0.0.0) it goes from 1 to 3. This means that at level 2 (position 0.0), it includes records 1 and 2. But then by depth 4 (position 0.0.0.0), no new records are processed, but by depth 5 (position 0.0.0.0.0), we've added 2 more records (`id: 5` now). So at depth 4, we should add 2 more records

So the output for the first few tree nodes *linked to records* should be:

```
const filledTree = {
  id: 1,
  children: [
    {
      id: 1,
      records: [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 } ],
      children: [
        {
          id: 3,
          children: [
            {
              id: 3,
              records: [ { id: 3 }, { id: 4 } ],
              children: [
                {
                  id: 5,
                  records: [ { id: 5 }, ..., { id: 9 } ],
                },
                {
                  id: 10,
                  records: [ { id: 10 }, ..., { id: 16 } ],
                },
                ...
```

Notice how it only adds the records *once the next node in the traversal changes*. And it adds all nodes up to `id - 1`.

How can you construct an algorithm for this in JavaScript? What I have so far (above) is convoluted and I am getting confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was because my `iterativeDFS` was wrong. Any ideas how to fix it? I got it working with recursion I think:

```js
function traverse(tree) {
  const traversed = collect(tree)
  let i = 0
  while (i < traversed.length) {
    let current = traversed[i++]
    let next = traversed[i]

    // mutable hack
    current.records = []

    if (!next) return

    // get diff to know how many records to add.
    let diff = next.id - current.id
    if (diff) {
      let records = listOfRecords.splice(0, diff)
      current.records.push(...records)
    }
  }
}

function collect(start) {
  const list = []
  recursiveDFS(start, node => list.push(node))
  return list
}

function recursiveDFS(start, callback) {
  callback(start)
  start.children?.forEach(child => {
    recursiveDFS(child, callback)
  })
}
```